# How can i make my Spring Batch job to restart from a specific value in the database column?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job that reads a database table and updates it with a chunk size of 5.

select * from table where col1 is null;

The batch job updates the column 'col1' sometimes and sometimes not based on business rules.

If the job fails, it is not restarting from where it left off. It skips some of the chunks as the query "select * from table where col1 is null;" will return a new result set as the previous run updated some of the col1 values.

Now instead of using the default execution context state for restart, can i use a specific value of Col1 say 50, and make the restart run all the records with col1 > 50 ?

Comment: Which item reader do you use? The dataset returned by a query like `select * from table where col1 is null` is not fixed, how can you (or Spring Batch) "track" the progress of its processing to restart where it left off upon a failure? To correctly restart a job instance on failure, the input dataset should be fixed.

Comment: I am using JdbcCursorItemReader. I am thinking of a solution like adding an order by clause to the query like "select * from table where col1 is null order by column2". Then if i store the last column2 value that was processed before failure in executioncontext or somewhere. And then can i process only those records whose column2 > (stored column2 value from context) ?

Comment: Yes, that might work. You could pass the last value of the previous run as a job parameter and make the reader read data from the last value onward.